# UE4 Dynamic delegate ExcuteIfBound not execute my function

Tags: delegates, unreal-engine4

```
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_DELEGATE_OneParam(FTcpSocketDisconnectDelegate, int32, connectionID);
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_DELEGATE_OneParam(FTcpSocketConnectDelegate, int32, connectionID);
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_DELEGATE_TwoParams(FTcpSocketReceivedMessageDelegate, int32,connectionID, TArray<uint8>&, message);
```

I write three delegates in my class and i bound function by BindDynamic macro

```
FTcpSocketDisconnectDelegate disconnectDelegate;
disconnectDelegate.BindDynamic(this, &AGameTcpSocketConnection::OnDisconnected);
FTcpSocketConnectDelegate connectDelegate;
connectDelegate.BindDynamic(this, &AGameTcpSocketConnection::OnConnected);
FTcpSocketReceivedMessageDelegate receivedDelegate;
receivedDelegate.BindDynamic(this, &AGameTcpSocketConnection::OnMessageReceived);

disconnectDelegate.Execute(0);
connectDelegate.Execute(0);
TArray<uint8> message;
receivedDelegate.ExecuteIfBound(0, message);
```

But Execute and ExecuteIfBound not work and function doesn't called.
I check it at DebugGame mode but it doesn't work
How can I make this right?
Please help me.

Comment: Are your functions using the `UFUNCTION` specifier? Execute should throw an error if they're not, maybe they're silenced or were only added recently?

Comment: My functions using the UFUNCTION specifier and Execute doesn't throw an error, and I added these functions long time ago. And I comfile my scrypt. In DebugGame mode, those three delegates have right pointer of functions, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
FTcpSocketDisconnectDelegate disconnectDelegate;
FTcpSocketConnectDelegate connectDelegate;
FTcpSocketReceivedMessageDelegate receivedDelegate;

disconnectDelegate.AddDynamic(this, &AGameTcpSocketConnection::OnDisconnected);
connectDelegate.AddDynamic(this, &AGameTcpSocketConnection::OnConnected);
receivedDelegate.AddDynamic(this, &AGameTcpSocketConnection::OnMessageReceived);


if (disconnectDelegate.IsBound())
    disconnectDelegate.Broadcast(0);
if (connectDelegate.IsBound())
    connectDelegate.Broadcast(0);

TArray<uint8> message;
if (receivedDelegate.IsBound())
    receivedDelegate.Broadcast(0, message);
```